# How to find type of datatype stored in string

Tags: c#, reflection

I have extracted input and output parameters from wsdl and stored in string.
example: string `type=parameterType`.
output: `type="int"`.

Now, I want to get the default value of this type (in this case `int`).

I have tried this: `type.GetType()`. Result is the type of the class String, however, I want the value's type.

This is so I can get the default value of the actual value's type, not the default value of string e.g. `int` ==> `0` and not `"int"` ==> `string` ==> `null`.

Comment: If you've stored as string, then it's working exactly as intended.  I guess do you know the possible types the data may be able to be cast to?  if so, you can do a series of `TryParse` statements to try and pull back the data in their original format.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always same(first type then value)you can use `String.Split` to extract type as string and then you can do `if(typeString == "int")` then from string to int `int x = int.Parse(valueString);` Hope that gives you an idea to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Given the name of the type, you need to use reflection to find the actual type, then get its default value. However, since the type name for `int` is `System.Int32`, you'll need to go through a dictionary, e.g.:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"int", "System.Int32"},
};

var typeName = "int";
if (dictionary.ContainsKey(typeName))
    typeName = dictionary[typeName];
var type = Type.GetType(typeName);

var defaultValue = type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null;
```